# How do I connect by React frontend to my Rails API backend ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, actioncable

I'm trying to connect by React frontend to my RailsAPI backend ActionCable using ReactActionCableProvider package.

I've tried to use the ReactActionCableProvider to link to my Rails API cable route. I put a byebug on the connect function in my connection.rb file, but it never hits the byebug. This is my first time working with web sockets.

connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      byebug
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end
```

App.js

```
import ActionCableProvider from 'react-actioncable-provider'

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <ActionCableProvider url="ws://localhost:3001/cable">
      <div className="App">
        <Test />
      </div>
      </ActionCableProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect my code to hit the byebug when I load my app. Instead, I don't have any errors, and the rails server runs without hitting the byebug.

Edit: So after looking at the network tab and my server log, it seems that the connection is never made. I still do not know why ActionCableProvider never attempts to connect to my rails api.

Comment: Check requests in your browser `network` tab and server logs. What does it say?

Comment: Also do you have this line in `routes.rb`? `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`

Comment: I do have that line in routes.rb. My network tab has a websocket request with a status code of 101. The response header has Connection: Upgrade and Upgrade: websocket